# How to detect rate of change in a stream of data Python3

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

I have an input source that gives me integers in `[0..256]`.

I want to be able to locate spikes in this data, i.e. a new input.
I've tried using a rolling average in conjunction with finding the percent error. But this doesn't really work.

Basically, I want my program to find where a graph of the data would spike up, but I want it to ignore smooth transitions.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you could work with more than the first moment. What about assuming a given (rollingly centered) distribution and computing its, say, 95th centile, VS the spike value ?

Comment: @Tnerual I'm not very competent in this, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

A simple thought which follows my comment. First

```
>>> import numpy as np
```

Suppose we have the following time series

```
>>> sample = np.random.random_integers(0,256,size=(100,))
```

To know whether or not a spike can be considered as a rare event, we have to know the likelihood associated to each event. Since you are dealing with "rates of change", let us compute those

```
>>> sample_vars = np.abs(-1 + 1.*sample[1:]/sample[:-1]) # the "1.*" to get floats... (python<3)
```

We can then define the variation which has at most 5 percent (sample-) chance of occurring

```
>>> spike_defining_threshold = np.percentile(sample_vars, 95)
```

Finally if `sample_vars[-1]>spike_defining_threshold`

Would be great if others have thoughts to share as well...